# Differentiability of the limits of sequences of functions from $\mathbb R$ to a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, banach-spaces, sequence-of-function

Let $(E, \|\cdot\|)$ be a real Banach space and $X$ an open subset of $\mathbb R$. I'm trying to prove below result which is used in the proof of Hille-Yosida theorem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*.

> Let $f_n, f, g: X \to E$ such that $f_n \in C^1 (X; E)$ for $n \ge 1$. Assume that
>
> - $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$, and
> - $(f'_n)$ converges locally uniformly to $g$, i.e., for each $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly (for the supremum norm) to $g$ on $U$.
>
> Then $f \in C^1 (X; E)$ and $f'=g$. In addition, $(f_n)$ converges locally uniformly to $f$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

Fix $a \in X$. There is $r>0$ such that $B(a, r) \subset X$ and that $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $B(a, r)$. For each $x\in U:= B(a, r/2)$, we consider
$$
F : [0, 1] \to E, t \mapsto f_n(a+t(x-a)) - t f'_n (a)(x-a).
$$

We have $f_n$ is continuous on $\overline U$ and differentiable on $U$, so $F$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and differentiable on $(0, 1)$. Also,
$$
F' (t) = \big ( f'_n(a+t(x-a)) - f'_n (a) \big ) (x-a)
\quad \forall t \in (0, 1).
$$

By [mean value theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions), $\|F(1)-F(0)\| \le \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|F' (t)\|$. Then
$$
\|f_n (x) - f_n (a) - f'_n (a) (x-a)\| \le |x-a| \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|f'_n(a+t(x-a)) - f'_n (a)\|.
$$

By triangle inequality,
$$
\begin{align*}
 & \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|f'_n (a+t(x-a)) - f'_n (a)\| \\
\le{} & \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|f'_n (a+t(x-a)) - g(a+t(x-a))\| +\sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|g(a) - f'_n (a)\| \\
&\quad + \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|g(a+t(x-a)) - g (a)\|\\
\le{} & 2\|(f'_n-g)1_{U}\|_\infty + \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|g(a+t(x-a)) - g (a)\|.
\end{align*}
$$

Taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we get for all $x \in U \setminus \{a\}$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\|f (x) - f (a) - g (a) (x-a)\|}{|x-a|} \le  \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|g(a+t(x-a)) - g (a)\|.
\end{align*}
$$

We have $f'_n$ is continuous and $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $U$, so $g$ is continuous on $U$. This implies
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|g(a+t(x-a)) - g (a)\|=0.
$$

Thus
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{\|f (x) - f (a) - g (a) (x-a)\|}{|x-a|} =0.
$$

This implies $f'(a)=g(a)$. Since this holds for all $a\in X$, we get $f'=g$ and thus $f \in C^1 (X; E)$. It remains to prove that $(f_n)$ converges locally uniformly to $f$. We consider
$$
G : [0, 1] \to E, t \mapsto (f_n-f)(a+t(x-a)).
$$

We have $f_n,f$ are continuous on $\overline U$ and differentiable on $U$, so $G$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and differentiable on $(0, 1)$. Also,
$$
G' (t) = (f'_n-f')(a+t(x-a))(x-a)
\quad \forall t \in (0, 1).
$$

By mean value theorem, we get $\|G(1)-G(0)\| \le \sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|G' (t)\|$. Then for $x \in U$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\|f_n (x)-f(x) \| &\le \|(f_n (x)-f(x)) - (f_n (a)-f(a)) \| + \|f_n (a)-f(a) \| \\
&=\|G(1)-G(0)\|+\|f_n (a)-f(a) \| \\
&\le |x-a|\sup_{t \in (0, 1)} \|(f'_n-f')(a+t(x-a))\| + \|f_n (a)-f(a) \| \\
&\le r\|(f'_n-g)1_{U}\|_\infty + \|f_n (a)-f(a) \|.
\end{align*}
$$

The claim then follows.